# Can I update an app on Google Play Store using an Flutter project APK?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-play

The situation: I've created an Android app using Java some time ago. It's published on Google Play Store and it uses Firebase as back-end

Now I want to create another version of that app in Flutter - with a new design and other features.

My question is if I can update that already published app on Google Play Store using an APK generated from the Flutter project. Also, can I use the previous Firebase project for the new Flutter app?

Answer (score 2):

Yes if you have the keystore file you can develop with flutter and upgrade in play store for more details check this link
https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android

Answer (score 2):

Definitively you can. You need to be sure to:

- Sign the apk with the same key as your production build
- Use the same package name (yourcompany.yourapp.com)